# Get Phone Number dialled from Call app in another app

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

I was wondering is there way i could start my application (that stays in background).Dial some number from dialer and the application could know what is being dialed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that, not in the Apple way. And also anyone should not be able to do this, as this will be a major security / privacy threat. If this was able then it would be easy to collect all the numbers the person dialed and then send them to my own server.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to do what you are asking.

You can use [CTCallCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html) to detect that a call is outgoing but it will not tell you what the number is.

Comment: Can I use it to find if its an international number and open my application if thats the case.Thanks for the answers

Comment: It will only tell you when a phone call is in progress but no information about the phone call (like the phone number).  Also you can't "open you app" or "bring your app to the foreground", you can only use local notification's to notify the user and the user can select to run you app.  Welcome to the painful world of ios development...